# TF tells me to use Keras optimizer, tells me the opposite when I change it?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I have this piece of code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))  

learning_rate = 0.001
(1) optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
(2) optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'])
```

For the optimizer, at first I had line (1). It worked, but I got the following warning when making ModelCheckpoints:

> WARNING:tensorflow:TensorFlow optimizers do not make it possible to access optimizer attributes or optimizer state after instantiation. As a result, we cannot save the optimizer as part of the model save file.You will have to compile your model again after loading it. Prefer using a Keras optimizer instead (see keras.io/optimizers).

Apparently, you have to use the Keras optimizer if you want to use this. Ok, no problem, so I commented (1) out, and inserted (2).

Now it doesn't even want to compile anymore, and gives me this error instead:

> ValueError: optimizer must be an instance of tf.train.Optimizer, not a class 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers.Adam'

This sounds a bit contradictory to me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you to use the actual keras optimizer, not the tensorflow.keras class. Import Adam directly from keras library and it runs ok:

```
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout 
from keras.optimizers import Adam 

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=9, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))  

learning_rate = 0.001 
optimizer = Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'])
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem indeed!
I read in a tutorial somewhere that keras.* shouldn't be used anymore because it was deprecated, and that tf.keras.* would work for everything nowadays. I guess I was misinformed :)

Comment: No worries! I guess that they are indeed improving the tf.keras API to work robustly when using tensorflow. But, you need to stick to using tf. The main danger here is when mixing keras.io with tensorflow in the same script, which can cause such problems (e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083955/difference-between-keras-and-tf-keras-should-old-keras-code-be-changed) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821855/why-keras-does-not-allow-to-add-a-convolutional-layer-in-this-way/53821915#53821915)